# Save the data in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here I am trying to save the data in data base. Whatever data user enters it has to save in database and it has to save in page it self also. when user opens page that data has to display.

Code for aspx page

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCnct" Text="Contact Number" AssociatedControlID="txtCnct" CssClass="control-label" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCnct" CssClass="form-control" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAltCnct" Text="Alternative Contact Number" AssociatedControlID="txtAltCnct" CssClass="control-label" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAltCnct" CssClass="form-control" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEmcnct" Text="Emergency Contact Number" AssociatedControlID="txtEmrCnct" CssClass="control-label" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmrCnct" CssClass="form-control" />
```

Button code saving the data in database

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-label="Left Align" runat="server" onserverclick="btnContactInfoSave_click">
```

code for aspx.cs page
   btnContactInfoSave_click code for saving the data in database.

```
    protected void btnContactInfoSave_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    string[] ContactInfoData = new string[4];
                    ContactInfoData[0] = GlobalVars.UserEmail;
                    ContactInfoData[1] = txtCnct.Text;
                    ContactInfoData[2] = txtAltCnct.Text;
                    ContactInfoData[3] = txtEmrCnct.Text;
                    Utilities.sqlUploadContactInfoData(ContactInfoData);
                }
            }



public static void sqlUploadContactInfoData(string[] Userdata)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = jPortalDBConnection())
            {
                try
                {
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    string spName = "spUploadContactInfoData";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, sqlConn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtCnct", Userdata[0].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtAltCnct", Userdata[1].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtEmrCnct", Userdata[2].ToString());
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    ErrorMsg("Server Error", "Server Error ! Please try again Later.");
                }
            }
        }
```

After entering the data when I am trying to save the data it is not saving the data. button is not triggering. Any wrong in this code..???

Comment: Please fix your formatting of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with This. This is the way to Insert data into DB

```
SQL connection code for connecting database...
public static void sqlUploadContactInfoData(string[] Userdata)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = jPortalDBConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                string spName = "spUploadContactInfoData";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, sqlConn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtCnct", txtCnct.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtAltCnct", txtAltCnct.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtEmrCnct",  txtEmrCnct.Text);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                ErrorMsg("Server Error", "Server Error ! Please try again Later.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: but for other pages the above code is working fine. In my application I have 8 pages. One page it is working fine but from another page is not working..

Answer (score 0):

From your web from designer double click on the button check weather it pointing to the Button event you expected to be invoked.else this will create a event handler for you.

If you are assigning the click handler in code behind, make sure that it is not inside an `IsPostBack == false` check :

make sure `CausesValidation = "false"` attribute of button like:

```
runat="server" and  OnClick="btnContactInfoSave_click"  check these attribute exist in your asp button
```

Answer (score 0):

Try button in this way:

```
<asp:Button ID="AddMore_Button" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="btnContactInfoSave_click" />
```